# How to fetch records by comparing with date in flutter cloud firestore plugin?

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

Working on a flutter application where I'm using firebase cloud firestore for storing all my documents. My document has a **startDateTime** field having a format like this...

[image]

I want to fetch all records whose startDateTime is greater than or equal to current date. Here is my flutter code to do this...

```
Firestore.instance.collection("trips")
    .where("trip.createdByUID", isEqualTo: this.userDetails['id'])
    .where("trip.startDateTime", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: new DateTime.now().toString() )
    .getDocuments().then((string) {
        print('Firestore response111: , ${string.documents.length}');

        string.documents.forEach((doc) => print("Firestore response222: ${doc.data.toString()}" ));
    })
```

But this is not working. Can't able to understand how to use `isGreaterThanOrEqualTo` so that it'll work.

Need some guidance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Pass just this query

`.where("trip.startDateTime", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: new DateTime.now())`

Since firebase automatically converts dart `DateTime` object to Timestamp Firebase object. You also need to do the same when you save the object.

[image]

You can see on the right if the object type is timestamp.

In case this doesn't work, you can save another object on your creation in numeric format. Then it is easy to compare. You can get numeric dateTime like this:

`new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch`

Answer (score 2):

You can compare by anything like day or by hour using `DateTime()`:

```js
final response = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
   .collection('meetings')
   .where(
      'date',
      isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: DateTime(selectedDay.year, selectedDay.month, selectedDay.day)
   )
   .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working on iOS. Please check the code below.

```
DateTime _now = DateTime.now();

return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: _store
      .collection('rides')
      .orderBy('rideDate')
      .orderBy('rideType')
      .where('rideDate', isGreaterThan: _now)
      .snapshots(),
```