# Firestore Streams subscription

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am Designing a chat app at present with flutter, I'm using Firestore for this. I wanted to know how these streams work because I want to know the number of reads so that I can anticipate the limit. Say there are currently 315 messages and all of them are in the chat screen at present. If a person enters a new message it'll be the 316th message, so will flutter stream read all the 316 messages or just get the newly added message and append it to the list of 315 members.

I saw a lot of videos read blogs, they just miss out this point. I want to understand this clearly.

```dart
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _firestoreDatabase.collection(id).orderBy('time').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        } else {
          final messages = snapshot.data.documents.reversed;
          List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
          for (var message in messages) {
            final messageText = message.data['amount'];
            final messageSender = message.data['team'];
            final timeDisp = message.data['timedisp'];
            final currentUser = teamName;

            bool isManager;
            if (messageSender.toString() == 'Manager') {
              isManager = true;
            } else {
              isManager = false;
            }

            final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
              sender: messageSender,
              text: messageText.toString(),
              isMe: currentUser == messageSender,
              timeDisp: timeDisp,
              isManager: isManager,
            );
            messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
          }

    return Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              reverse: true,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
              children: messageBubbles,
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the query code you're working with so we can better understand what you're doing.

Comment: Yess, I've added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform a query an stream from it, it will initially read all of the matching documents.  The documents are cached in memory for as long as the stream is active.  If a new document would match the query, only the new document would be read, and everything else would be reused from memory.  It would not read all the previously cached documents again.

Comment: Thank you soo much. This is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Just a clarification, cached memory is the memory cached in our mobile device right ?

Answer (score 0):

The way you get the Documents from a Firestore Stream will depend on the Query that you perform on probably a StreamBuilder widget.

If you want, you can make it so the new member of the chat gets all the Firestore Documents that are available on your Database for the current Chat, or just the newest ones by adding a timestamp parameter and then querying the snapshot like this:

```
Firebase.instance().collection("Chats").where("sentTimestamp",isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: new DateTime.now())
```

You can learn more about fetching and comparing by dates on the following question:
[How to fetch records by comparing with date in flutter cloud firestore plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50663556/how-to-fetch-records-by-comparing-with-date-in-flutter-cloud-firestore-plugin)

Comment: Just to be clear, this is GreaterThanorEqualTo will compare all the data(timestamp) in the firestore database and will just take the message which is the latest right ?

Comment: Exactly. That way you filter out the not desired documents.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your help. Learnt a new method today !

Comment: Make sure you create the timestamp field and save it on the Database when a message gets added. Good Luck!

Comment: I also faced another issue, as I am using datetime.now() for the timestamp to sort the messages, some of my friends time are like 2 seconds fast or some kind the message then get sorted in a wrong way. Can you suggest a better way to find the correct time please.

Comment: You can use the server timestamp. Refer to this
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907151/flutter-firestore-server-side-timestamp)